# Oracle - Failover table or query manipulation

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse

In a DWH environment for performance reasons I need to materialize a view into a table with approx. 100 columns and 50.000.000 records. Daily ~ 60.000 new records are inserted and ~80.000 updates on existing records are performed. By decision I am not allowed to use materialized views because the architect claims this leads to performance issues. I can't argue the case anymore, it's an irrevocable decision and I have to accept.
So I would like to make a daily full load in the night e.g. truncate and insert. But if the job fails the table may not be empty but must contain the data from the last successful population.
Therefore I thought about something like a failover table, that will be used instead if anything wents wrong:

IF v_load_job_failed THEN failover_table
ELSE regular_table

Is there something like a failover table that will be used instead of another table depending on a predefined condition? Something like a trigger that rewrites or manipulates a select-query before execution?

I know that is somewhat of a dirty workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have space for (brief) period of time of double storage, I'd recommend

1) Clone existing table (all indexes, grants, etc) but name with _TMP
2) Load _TMP
3) Rename base table to _BKP
4) Rename _TMP to match Base table
5) Rename _BKP to _TMP
6) Truncate _TMP

ETA: #1 would be "one time"; 2-6 would be part of daily script.

This all assumes the performance of (1) detecting all new records and all updated records and (2) using MERGE (INSERT+UPDATE) to integrate those changed records into base table is "on par" with full load.

(Personally, I lean toward the full load approach anyway; on the day somebody tweaks a referential value that's incorporated into the view def and changes the value for all records, you'll find yourself waiting on a week-long update of 50,000,000 records.  Such concerns are completely eliminated with full-load approach)

All that said, it should be noted that if MV is defined correctly, the MV-refresh approach is identical to this approach in every way, except:
1) Simpler / less moving pieces
2) More transparent (SQL of view def is attached to MV, not buried in some PL/SQL package or .sql script somewhere)
3) Will not have "blip" of time, between table renames, where queries / processes may not see table and fail.

ETA: It's possible to pull this off with "partition magic" in a couple of ways that avoid a "blip" of time where data or table is missing.

You can, for instance, have an even-day and odd-day partition.  On odd-days, insert data (no commit), then truncate even-day (which simultaneously drops old day and exposes new).  But is it worth the complexity?  You need to add a column to partition by, and deal with complexity of reruns - if you're logic isn't tight, you'll wind up truncating the data you just loaded.  This does, however, prevent a blip

One method that does avoid any "blip" and is a little less "whoops" prone:
1) Add "DUMMY" column that always has value 1.
2) Create _TMP table (also with "DUMMY" column) and partition by DUMMY column (so all rows go to same partition)
-- Daily script --
3) Load _TMP table
4) Exchange partition of _TMP table with main base table WITHOUT VALIDATION INCLUDING INDEXES

It bears repeating: all of these methods are equivalent if resource usage to MV-refresh; they're just more complex and tend to make developers feel "savvy" for solving problems that have already been solved.

Final note - addressing David Aldridge - first and foremost, daily refresh tables SHOULD NOT have logging enabled.  In recovery scenario, just make sure you have step to run refresh scripts once base tables are restored.

Performance-wise, mileage is going to vary on this; but in my experience, the complexity of identifying and modifying changed/inserted rows can get very sticky (at some point, somebody will do something to base data that your script did not take into account; either yielding incorrect results or performance obstacles).  DWH environments tend to be geared to accommodate processes like this with little problem.  Unless/until the full refresh proves to have overhead above&beyond what the system can tolerate, it's generally the simplest "set-it-and-forget-it" approach.

On that note, *if* data can be logically separated into "live rows which might be updated" vs "historic rows that will never be updated", you can come up with a partitioning scheme and process that only truncates/reloads the "live" data on a daily basis.

Comment: On of the problem I see with the full load is that the duration of the job is related to the total amount of data in the table, not the volume of changes. So while you're quite right that there may be a need for a full reload at some time (and in particular you need the space to be able to do it) I would be concerned about the jobs increasing duration and increased size of redo archive. OTOH one advantage of full reloads is that it lets you use economical compression techniques, of course, to reduce data size.

Comment: I just had another idea: What about loading the data into a dedicated TEMP partiton of the same table and move that partition after successful population in the regular partiton. Would that be a sensible approach?

Comment: There are lots of variations of this.  Appending answer to give overview - generally each is doing the exact same thing (load data where it can't be seen, swap with old data, drop old data).

Comment: Ref logging -- I can see why you might say that if every day's raw data was a complete data set, but not otherwise of course.

Comment: Bear in mind also that this is a case of new records being 0.12% of total, and modified records being 0.16% of total. Even with redo and undo on table and index of both new and updated records, that is probably much less i/o than recreating the complete table and all of its indexes, and i/o is almost always the choke point on data warehouses. Depends a bit on the update detection query, of course.

Answer (score 0):

A materialized view is just a set of metadata with an underlying table, and there's no reason why you cannot maintain a table in a manner similar to a materialized view's internal mechanisms.

I'd suggest using a MERGE statement as a single query rather than a truncate/insert. It will either succeed in its entirety or rollback to leave the previous data intact. 60,000 new records and 80,000 modified records is not much.

I think that you cannot go far wrong if you at least start with a simple, single SQL statement and then see how that works for you. If you do decide to go with a multistep process then ensure that it automatically recovers itself at any stage where it might go wrong part way through -- that might turn out to be the tricky bit.